# How can I convert my firebase table of "Request" into tables in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I have four simple columns:

```
address, name, phone num, total price
```

and an array of "Foods" which have some columns like

```
Id, discount, description i.e
```

Please kindly suggest how many tables which relation should be used in it.

Note: it is for online food delivery app

Here is a screenshot of my table request in firebase :

[image]

Comment: As per my knowledge, it can not be said these number of tables you need in your relational database. at first, you have to design your relational database as per your requirements and then you can easily Identify which data goes where.

Comment: boss you from pak understand urdu ?

Comment: @mohammad Saleh no boss, i'm neither from pak or understand urdu..

Comment: ok thansk basically i am an android developer with very short knowledge of back end that's y struggling its my final year project in university i made it in firebase but supervisor force me to do so in sql server with api in asp[.net so very tensed these days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a head start:

```
CREATE TABLE Request (
    RequestID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    address VARCHAR(1000),
    name VARCHAR(1000),
    phone VARCHAR(100),
    total DECIMAL(10,2))

CREATE TABLE RequestContent (
    RequestContentID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, -- Generate a primary key for each record (identity)
    RequestID INT,
    productDiscount DECIMAL(10,2),
    productId INT,
    productName VARCHAR(100), -- You might want to leave the name out and have it on a "Product" table
    productPrice DECIMAL(10,2),
    productQuantity INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (RequestID) REFERENCES Request (RequestID))
```

You might want to review the proper data type for each one.

Comment: Can I use phone num as a foriegn key ? and make phn num in pk in request table ?

Comment: Yes, you could but I'd call it `Client` instead of `Request` then. And will have to create another `Request` table where you can store the total amount, date, etc.

Comment: ok thansk 
basically i am an android developer with very short knowledge of back end that's y struggling its my final year project in university i made it in firebase but supervisor force me to do so in sql server with api in asp[.net so very tensed these days